# How to add a string value in a number format field in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I need some help in doing my crystal report. I'm a newbie here.
Well, I am trying to add a string value in a number format field. 
The value is 1 and I'm trying to add 'LAYER' in the field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your Field1 = 1 and Field2 = Layer Than

Create one formula formula1 =

```
Totext({Field1}) + " " +  {Field2}
```

or

```
CSTR({Field1}) + " Layer"
```

by this way you can do this.

Comment: Got it already. I created a formula fields using If...Else

if GroupName ({GroupName}) = "1" then
"1ST LAYER"
else 
"2ND LAYER"

Thanks for your respon Hiren gardhariya :)